# poetry built package with os-specific dependencies

Tags: python, python-poetry

I've built a package using poetry. The package uses geopandas (which means in turn GDAL, Fiona as well).

GDAL is a notoriously pain to install on windows and I ended with a pyproject.toml file using an os-specific dependency description, ie :

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
dukpy = [
    {platform = 'windows', url = "https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/dukpy-0.2.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"},
    {platform = 'linux', version = "~0.2"},
    ]    
Rtree = "^1.0.0"
GDAL = [
    {platform = 'windows', url = "https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/GDAL-3.4.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"},
    {platform = 'linux', version = "~3.4"},
    ]
Fiona = [
    {markers = "sys_platform == 'win64'", url = "https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/Fiona-1.8.21-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"},
    {markers = "sys_platform == 'linux'", version = "~1.8"}
    ]
geopandas = "^0.11.1"
```

The package was built using poetry (on a linux server) and runs well. When I try to install it (using pip) on a windows machine, python tries to install all dependencies from pypi (right now for instance, it downloads Fiona-1.8.21.tar.gz instead of downloading the pre-compiled whl).

**Question :** is this possible to retain the os-specific dependencies after building the wheel ?

*Note 1 : I'm aware how to perform the installation on windows : I can install manually all dependecies from url first and my built package afterwards. But I hope there is an easier way to perform this task.*

*Note 2 : I'm aware the lfd "repo" is archived, but these are still working and up to date - for now...*

---

**EDIT**

Extract from the medata file:

```
Requires-Python: >=3.9,<4.0
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10
Requires-Dist: Fiona (>=1.8,<1.9); sys_platform == "linux"
Requires-Dist: Fiona @ https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/Fiona-1.8.21-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl ; sys_platform == "win64"
Requires-Dist: GDAL (>=3.4,<3.5); sys_platform == "linux"
Requires-Dist: GDAL @ https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/GDAL-3.4.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl ; sys_platform == "windows"
Requires-Dist: Rtree (>=1.0.0,<2.0.0)
Requires-Dist: geopandas (>=0.11.1,<0.12.0)
```

It keeps the os-specific description indeed...

Comment: It would probably be easier just to add `--find-links` to your pip (or equivalent) invocation, pointing towards e.g. a "simple" style HTTP index page (e.g. https://pypi.org/simple/babel/) that has links to, or a directory containing the wheels. That way the installer can just notice the wheels and you don't need to explicitly tell it where to find them.

Comment: @AKX saddly I don't think this exists for GDAL on windows ? (therefore the use of the lfd pseudo repo)

Comment: No, one might not currently exist, but unless you want to host such a page, you can instruct your Windows users to download wheels from wherever they can find them and use `--find-links`.

Comment: @AKX : agreed (and finally not so different from what I indicated in "Note 1") ; that beeing said, it's beside the point of the question (ie the possibility to retain the os-specific description of dependencies in pyproject.toml after building the package).

Comment: Can you show what the `METADATA` file within the built wheel (it's a zip file) contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right – the thing is that [`sys.platform()`, i.e. the `sys_platform` marker's value](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/sys.html#sys.platform), is always `win32`, never `windows` or `win64`.

Those `windows` or `win64` dependencies will never get selected, since they don't match.

You can find [the known environment markers here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers); `platform_system == "Windows"` could apparently also work.

Try with

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
dukpy = [
    {platform = 'win32', url = "https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/dukpy-0.2.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"},
    {platform = 'linux', version = "~0.2"},
    ]    
Rtree = "^1.0.0"
GDAL = [
    {platform = 'win32', url = "https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/GDAL-3.4.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"},
    {platform = 'linux', version = "~3.4"},
    ]
Fiona = [
    {platform = "win32", url = "https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/Fiona-1.8.21-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"},
    {platform = "linux", version = "~1.8"}
    ]
geopandas = "^0.11.1"
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Odd behaviour though and (IMH) not documented enough... I'll check if that explanation can be added to poetry's doc. Thanks !

Comment: @tgrandje _What_ is odd behaviour? You presumably wrote the TOML file yourself and didn't double-check whether your `platform` markers are correct..?

Comment: Well, I find the whole "win32" thing strange, but that one's on me I suppose. In fact I ran into a lot of troubles with this TOML (including mixed case modules' names when using poetry's API for adding modules from URL/pypi) and I checked a lot of things about platform identifications. I sure double-checked on linux, but I may have missed this one on windows... In any case, poetry's doc is **not** very straightfoward about platforms (it used to be easier with the "platform" argument which is not documented anymore). More to the point, I hope this Q/A will help reference this!