# Architecture dependent requirements with `poetry`

Tags: python-3.x, cross-platform, pywin32, python-poetry

I am supporting a system which is main running Python 3.10 on Windows but has limited delivery on Linux. We use `poetry` to manage the package environment.

For NTLM authentication with requests, I introduced a dependency on the `requests_negotiate_sspi` package, which brings in `pywin32`. When I run this on Windows, everything works, but when I try `poetry install` on Linux, I get a

```
RuntimeError: Unable to find installation candidates for pywin32 (306)
```

If I understand correctly, this is an issue since no such package exists for Linux, which makes sense. I don't execute this dependency on Linux.

Could I make a conditional dependency in `poetry`, where it would only depend on this package when running under Windows, but not on Linux? If not, what other options do I have to deal with this issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631683/poetry-built-package-with-os-specific-dependencies?rq=2